# What is the name of the eleventh Rudra from whom Lord Hanuman emanated?

Tags: hanuman, rudra

It is very confusing because the names change with different scriptures. Does it mention anywhere in scriptures the name of Rudra, said to be the eleventh Rudra who emanated as Lord Hanuman?